# laravel 5.6 error en migracion

Tags: laravel

Intento crear un login en laravel 5.6 y a la hora de realizar la migracion me sale el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿cuál es el código de la migración?

Comment: Ahi lo subi.....

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente tu versión de MySQL es menor a 5.7; entonces en los campos de tipo índice no esta especificada la longitud, puedes solucionarlo de los siguientes modos:

1. Abre el archivo llamado AppServiceProvider.php y coloca dentro del método boot la siguiente instrucción

> Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

Y al mismo tiempo en la parte superior justo debajo después del namespace App\Providers, declara también esta línea de código

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

2. Si te llega a ser posible actualiza tu versión de MySQL a 5.7
3. Sigue trabajando con tu versión regular de MySQL y a cada campo que este declarado como index o unique pasale también dentro la longitud que deben poseer; del modo siguiente:

`php
<?php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',100)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`

> En el código anterior notas como en la línea del string email le paso
>   despúés del nombre también una longtitud de 100

Answer (score 1):

Nota: deberías subir código en texto para hacerlo mas fácil.

El error se produce en ciertos motores de bases de datos debido al juego de caracteres y la codificación, según la codificación cada char puede ocupar 1, 2, ó 4 bytes (utf8, utf8mb4) y eso hace llegar al límite máximo el tipo `varchar` para definir la unique key .

En cada línea que dice `$table->string` prueba agregarle el numero máximo de caracteres `(190)`

por ejemplo:

```
$table->string('name', 190);
```

mas info: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819016/1423096

Answer (score 0):

tienes que añadirle una longitud **a los campos únicos** y **a los que son llaves como index**, en tu caso debes modificar:

```
$table->string('email',120)->unique();
```